# Dynamics CRM 2013 custom action and process entity privilege

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We recently faced an issue with Process entity privilege which could well be a design problem in Dynamics CRM itself. Or may be we're doing something we're not supposed to.

As you all know Process is a common entity for new **Custom Action** feature and the original Workflows. We used a few custom actions in the system to improve form load performance and make some processes transaction aware.

The problem is that users need **organization level** read access on Process entity to make a call to these custom actions which is ridiculous. There was a requirement for users to have limited access to workflows but since the custom actions and workflows share the same privilege through Process entity, this is impossible to fulfill.

For server side custom pages and plugins we can impersonate as a privileged user but most of these custom actions are being called from JavaScript (we used it to speed up form load by aggregating queries into single web service call)

Is there a way we can limit users access to workflow and still be able to let them call custom actions?

Another question is that are custom actions not meant to be used in this way? Which, if no, would makes custom actions quite useless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't found a way to accomplish this in the past due to the reasons you explain. You could always jury-rig a custom action through the use of a retrieve of a custom entity and implement the action in a retrieve plugin, but it is neither straight forward nor easy.

Comment: Hmm.. this is a pretty big set back in making good use of custom actions! Either way, the project went live and we can't make major code changes to the system anymore.Yes, we used to create a custom entity for this purpose in older versions and I was hopeful that we wouldn't need it anymore when the custom action was introduced.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you would need to restrict read access on Workflows...I've never had this requirement come up and I'm not sure what it would really accomplish. Giving Read won't allow a user to create new Workflows.

Comment: It won't give create privilege but it still allows users to execute workflows.